# Jtable to TextArea in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist, jtable

I need some help understanding why the ArrayList is not being populated,

I am trying to pass information Stored in a jTable that is on a JFrame to a JTextArea taht is on another JFrame, i curently have the following code but for some reason the information is not being passed, it stays Empty

I dont want Anyone to do my HW for me i just need to be pointed in the right direction,

here is the Code i did so far.

```
     public ArrayList<String> extractTableInfo() {

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    int nRow = model.getRowCount(), nCol = model.getColumnCount();


    ArrayList<String> extractedInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    String rowInfo = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCol; j++) {
            rowInfo = rowInfo + (String) model.getValueAt(i, j);
        }
        extractedInfo.add(rowInfo);
    }

    return extractedInfo;
}
```

Thats in the First JFrame and in the second JFrame on button Click i have

```
     private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    Generate_Teams gt = new Generate_Teams();

     ArrayList<String> TableInformation = new ArrayList<String>();

     for(int i =0; i < gt.extractTableInfo().size(); i++){         
     TableInformation.add(gt.extractTableInfo().get(i));
     }



    for (int i = 0; i < TableInformation.size(); i++) {
        jTextArea1.append(TableInformation.get(i));
    }


}
```

i would apriciate any help you can give.

Thx in advance.....

Fix....

Thx for your help fixed it like this,

```
 Edit ed = new Edit(extractTableInfo());

 ed.setVisible(true);
```

that is in the First Frame and in the second frame i did this

```
private ArrayList<String> infogot = new ArrayList<String>();

  public Edit(ArrayList<String> getinfo)
 { 
   initComponents();
   this.infogot = getinfo;

 }


   for (int i = 0; i < infogot.size(); i++) {
      jTextArea1.append(String.valueOf(infogot.get(i)));
    }
```

And it worked like this

Comment: It is good practice to follow naming conventions. In Java, convention is that only class names have a first uppercase letter. Thus, your `TableInformation` should by convention be called `tableInformation`. Following these conventions will increase the readability of your code - for instance, at first glance `TableInformation.get(i)` looks like a static call to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try debugging your code. It might help adding print statements to check if the ArrayList returned by the `extractTableInfo` method contains the contents of the table.

Also, the loop below could be improved:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gt.extractTableInfo().size(); i++) {
   TableInformation.add(gt.extractTableInfo().get(i));
}
```

It looks like whenever you call extractTableInfo you are creating a new ArrayList and populating it from the table over and over again.

Instead use:

```
ArrayList<String> extractedInfo = gt.extractTableInfo();
for (int i = 0; i < extractedInfo.size(); i++) {
   TableInformation.add(extractedInfo.get(i));
}
```

Or even better, use:

```
TableInformation.addAll(gt.extractTableInfo());
```

Comment: Or even better: don't copy all the elements from one list to another: it's completely unnecessary. Directly use the list returned by gt.extractTableInfo()

Comment: i did a litle bit of testing and tryed to diplay the extractTableInfo() into the same jFrame and the return was not Empty the data got displayed, i think the problem is when i am passing the data from one JFrame to the other,

    ArrayList<String> extractedInfo = gt.extractTableInfo();
     for (int i = 0; i < extractedInfo.size(); i++) {
       TableInformation.add(extractedInfo.get(i));
        }

that is how it was at the start

Thanks for all you help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, your problem is that `extractTableInfo()` always returns an empty ArrayList.

Since you have the row

```
extractedInfo.add(rowInfo);
```

In your code, `extractedInfo` should not be empty if that row is ever executed. Even if `rowInfo` were `null`, which it never is, it would be added to the list. With that in mind, are you **sure** that `nRow` (and `nCol`) are greater than zero? That's the only reason I can see that would keep the mentioned row from being executed.

Comment: i did a litle bit of testing and tryed to diplay the    extractTableInfo()    into the same jFrame and the return was not Empty the data got Displayed, i think the problem is when i am passing the data from one JFrame to the other,

Comment: Try debugging `jButton3ActionPerformed` and check if `TableInformation` is empty or contains only empty strings.

Comment: TableInformation is empty, i was going to make an overloaded constuctor and pass the array list from there, is it possible to make an overloaded constructor as data type ArrayList<String> ?

Comment: My bad, I meant check if `gt.extractTableInfo()` returns an empty list or a list of only empty strings. If that is the case, that would suggest that `gt.extractTableInfo()` does not operate on the same object as the one you use when you get it to work. Also, I don't quite understand your question. What do you want to overload?

Comment: i was thinking of doind something like this

Comment: private ArrayList<String> infogot = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public Edit(ArrayList<String> getinfo)
    {
        this.infogot = getinfo;
        
    }                                                                                                                                       i would put that in the  2nd Jframe, and something like this in the first JFrame                                                                  Edit ed = new Edit(extractTableInfo());

Comment: Thx for all your help it worked by passing the data through an overloaded constructor as i showed before thx again